# Multiple Rules for Single Target -- Doesn't Work as Expected

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here's a shortened version of the Makefile I am fighting with on a Linux system:

```
VPATH=altsrc:src:obj

OBJECTS=\
     nondepcode1.o \
     nondepcode2.o \
     nondepcode3.o \
     depcode1.o    \
     depcode2.o    \
     depcode3.o

DEP_OBJS= depcode1.o depcode2.o depcode3.o


# Targets

execute: $(OBJECTS)
gfortran -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)

$(DEP_OBJS): npts.h


obj/%.o: %.f
$(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) $< -o $@
obj/%.o: %.f90
$(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Rules

.f.o:
$(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) -o obj/$@ $<

%.o: %.f90
$(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) -o obj/$@ $<
```

I was expecting that the three objects that depend on "npts.h" would be automatically updated on a run of make (or gmake) if npts.h was more recent than any of the objects.  This just does not happen.  Make (and gmake) thinks the objects are up to date.  AFAICT, I am doing things the way they are described in the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html).  Anyone have any idea why make/gmake is not doing what I expected?  Thanks.  BTW, there are tabs at the beginning of all the recipe lines in the actual Makefile.  They went away here.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: Make (GNUMake 3.80) rebuilds the objects that are older than `npts.h`. Can you tell us what version of make you're using?

Comment: Thank you very much for checking.  My make version is GNU Make 3.81, running on x86_64-redhat-linux.  Thanks again.

Comment: Major egg on my face.  As I said, this was a shortened version of the Makefile.  I found the bug in the real Makefile.  Had some misnamed macros.  Not too experienced with the finer points of this stuff.  Mea culpa.  Very sorry.  Thanks for checking.

Comment: OK, Jack Kelly.  Done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major egg on my face. As I said, this was a shortened version of the Makefile. I found the bug in the real Makefile. Had some misnamed macros. Not too experienced with the finer points of this stuff. Mea culpa. Very sorry. Thanks for checking.